# Does Heroku allow NET::FTP binary file transfers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I can make a connection to an ftp server using NET::FTP, but it doesn't appear that I can use net::ftp.getbinaryfile() or even get something like the pwd(), list(), etc. Does heroku support this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Heroku does support NET::FTP and transferring files in binary mode. However, I found out that it only support passive mode [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542916/ftp-to-rails-app-hosted-on-heroku).

Answer (score 0):

Heroku would compile your code into slug, which is a read-only package ready for running in dynos, see: [Slug Compiler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler)

Your application is running in a very restricted environment, where most file operations are banned.

Comment: How do people achieve things like importing data from a csv?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Maybe I wasn't clear that I am using the cedar stack. This stack has a writeable file system, but the file are only available to the process that created them while that process is running.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how limited the file system access is. I was able to gunzip the file I downloaded.