# Direct FTP access to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ftp

Instead of having to go through a convoluted push process that takes several minutes to complete every time I make a minor change, I'd like direct FTP access to my files on the Heroku server.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5551464/671331

Comment: Not a duplicate. I just want to access it myself. I don't need it to be part of my application.

Comment: Fair enough. I want to say that it's not possible in the fact that Heroku doesn't allow access to the file system to the app, so I would assume accessing it using FTP isn't allowed.

Comment: Yeah I'm not entirely surprised but I figured that this is a question worth asking. Allowing the developers to access the file system is much less demanding than expecting the application itself to do so, so they may have allowed it under traditional hosting conventions. Maybe not.

Hopefully someone will come along and show how, but until then, I'll assume that you simply cannot do this.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.  I get the whole "rollback" and code management benefits to using the Git push method, but when you're both the dev and admin for a website, and your clients are being ridiculous with inane requests for on-the-fly upgrades, that FTP access is a lifesaver.  Really wish Heroku (and others) would implement this as standard

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is not possible. While directly pushing with FTP is more simple, it is a fragile means of deploying code and managing applications (hard to track what was done, difficult to reproduce or manage rollbacks, etc).

Comment: what is the best alternative to deploy and manage application in a less fragile way? Anything other than git?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Using the Git you can manage different version of your code

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try to Use [Dropbox Sync](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dropbox-sync) and deploy your app from Dropbox.

UPD: In July 2018 this feature was deprecated.