# Heroku Rails Console Write to Local File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, heroku, output

I want to pull some information from my database into a text file.

What's a good way to do that? I originally thought of running my heroku bash and rails console as I only need to do a simple loop to get the info I need. But I don't know the proper way to write to a file from heroku. It works in my local rails console

I've tried

```
File.open('text.txt', 'w') do |f|
    User.all.each do |u|
        f.puts u.email
    end
end
```

or something like `$stdout = File.new('/path/to/text.txt', 'w')`

but I think these files don't end up in my local directory...

How do I do this?

Alternate simple solutions also welcome since I didn't think I was doing anything overly complex

**Attempting Pakrash's answer**

In heroku bash + rails c

I put in

```
 require 'net/ftp'

ftp = Net::FTP.new('address.herokuapp.com','email@example.com', 'somepassword')
```

This just hangs though. No error.. I have to crl +c out of it

I previously had my full address https://adddress.herokuapp.com/ in there but it was  saying `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

Should I be entering this in differently?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku supports ftp in passive mode. So create the file on the server and download the file to local machine with ftp.

```
# FTPing from Heroku
ftp = Net::FTP.new(server, user, pass)
ftp.passive = true
ftp.getbinaryfile(remote_filename, tmp_filename)
```

References:

1. http://www.web-l.nl/posts/30-downloading-files-using-ftp-on-heroku
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570645/429758

Comment: silly quesion.. what am i putting for the `server, user` etc.

Comment: Server would be the site url `http://yoursite.herokuapp.com`; user id & password would be your heroku credentials.

Comment: i can just put this into rails c then directly? is there issue with inputting those values directly?

Comment: I've tried it like this after starting heroku bash and rails c. see revised question

Answer (score 2):

Perversely, I found the easiest thing to do was just to email the content to myself.

Comment: As well as this works, I've yet to find a good solution for files > 25MB, which is Gmail's attachment size limit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it's advisable, but you can actually start a rails console instance locally while connecting to the remote database on Heroku. Get the database connection information from the Heroku dashboard and add it to your local database.yml file in place of your regular development stanza. Something like

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: agblah9dff3
  host: ec2-44-333-444-100.compute-1.amazonaws.com
  pool: 5
  username: 8fk38hg72hd98d
  port: 5462
  password: 88dk3jblahblah8sk83df8sdfj23
  timeout: 5000
```

But know that you're playing with production code, so...you know, it's pretty risky.

A better idea might be to just use a database IDE that creates exports for you, or write a rake task that collects the info in a file and dumps it on S3. You won't be able to write files to disk Heroku.

Comment: well same as when i'm on my heroku bash no? but i guess you mean i can mistakenly forget that i'm in production while being in local..?

Comment: Yeah, it just seems risky to me to be mucking around in a console connected to production data. But it works in a pinch.